# ] command & command > [Ignore output]

Tags: linux, command, echo, output

```
[root@server1 ~]# perl file.pl & echo dog > custom-out.log &

[1] 24265

[2] 24266

cat

[root@server1 ~]#
```

I'd like to know how I can do this but at the same time not have it echo out

```
[1] 24265
[2] 24266
```

As you see I have perl.pl which takes a little while. I only want the results from echo. So I only want "cat" as the output instantly & breaking the console so ssh2 in php can read the result. hence the reason I need this.

Answer (score 2):

The messages noting that the processes were backgrounded is getting written to stderr by the shell. If you wrap this in a subshell and throw away its stderr you probably get what you expect.

```
( perl file.pl & echo dog > custom-log.out & ) 2>/dev/null
```

That said you almost certainly want to throw this into an actual file and execute that from your PHP code rather than rely on it invoking the shell correctly.